# Can power (in the context of work and energy) ever be negative?

Tags: energy, work, power

Consider this question which HAS definitely been asked but i ask you now to question your first inclination to just 'do the question' and explain the thought process. Restrictions: assume you only know work energy theorem, and the definition of power (average power = force * average velocity OR DELTA work/ DELTA time, instantaneous work = force * instantaneous velocity or dW/dt) So no potential energy as it shouldn't require it. and of course you have your kinemtaic equations with newtons laws.

"A 20.0-kg rock is sliding on a rough, horizontal surface at 8ms^-1
and eventually stops due to friction. The coefficient of
kinetic friction between the rock and the surface is 0.200. What
average power is produced by friction as the rock stops?"

so, going the long route (instead of force * average velocity * cosTheta, where theta is angle between the two vectors)

work total = work done by friction

```
        = (1/2*m*v_2)^2 - (1/2*m*v_1)^2 (work-energy theorem)
        = -640J (Keep in mind that the work done by friction is negative as the the displacement and force are indeed in different directions)
```

time taken for work:
v = v_0 + at

t = (v - v_0)/a

= (0-8)/(-mu_k*g) (net acceleration worked out through newtons second law)

=4.08s

Therefore, average power should be

average power = DELTA work/ DELTA time

```
            = (-640J - 0J)/(4.08s - 0s)
            =-157watts
```

i double checked everything and looked at other websites and it gives no mention of negative power... so what do you guys think?

Comment: There's a duality - positive work is always associated with negative work elsewhere in the system.

Comment: If I give you x blobs per second then I lose x blobs per second. For "blobs" read "energy".

Answer (score 1):

Negative power in this context would mean the same thing as negative work: negative work means that the system - in this case, the block - is having mechanical energy stolen from it, just as positive work means it's acquiring energy. The negative power then just means the *rate* of *losing* energy, here to friction, just as positive power is the rate of *accruing* energy.

ADD: I looked again and note the wording of the question says "find the average power PRODUCED" by the sliding. So this will and should be *positive*, not negative, even though the power of the frictional force on the rock is negative. As we're now looking at it from the point of view of the external world, which sees the rock as *producing* energy (thus the world is *accruing* energy *from* the rock) in the form of heat and sound (and work, in destroying the surfaces that are rubbing together), not from the point of view of the rock, which is having energy stolen from it. If it had said "find the power of the frictional force on the rock", *that* power would be negative, but it says find the produced power, which is the power given to the outside world, and that is positive, and is the exact negative of the figure you calculated, so +157 W is the answer.

Comment: so, power can be negative correct? that's basically all i need clarified. if you were to do this question would you get the same answer?

Comment: Yes. If you have negative work over time you get negative power, so the power of the frictional force (modeled with a point force at the center of mass of the body) should indeed be negative just as its work should be. But if you want to talk of the power deposited into the objects' internal structure which raises their temperature, _this_ power will be positive (and equal to the negative of the power of the frictional force), since it's energy going in. (ADD: actually, not quite equal, some of that energy ends up as sound, too, as well as breaking little dust crumbs off, but that's much

Comment: less I think. Ultimately though it _all_ is degraded to heat in the end, so...)

Comment: @CynicalAristocrat : Check this answer again. I read the question details again and noticed something I missed before.

Comment: THANK YOU, BEAUTIFUL HUMAN BEAN. IT HAS BEEN BOTHERING ME THE WHOLE DAY

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the system under consideration is the rock.

So your statement

> Keep in mind that the work done by friction is negative

If perhaps better written as

> Keep in mind that the work done **on the rock** by **the external force** (friction) is negative

The work done on the rock is negative because the change in kinetic energy of the rock is negative.

A negative amount of work done **on** the rock can be interpreted as a positive amount of work done **by** the rock.

Comment: i do understand that, but if you were to do the question would you get the same answer as me? or would it be different. If so, why the discrepancy (thats my main point because the answer is apparently 157 watts)

Comment: I would say that I would probably have said that the work done (power expended) by the frictional force on the rock was $\Large -$  .... J (W)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since power is rate at which work is done. So if work done is negative, time taken is positive, then power is negative. This would mean that the object is losing energy. On the other hand, positive power would mean that the object is gaining energy. Duality.